# Camera Follow Player when Moving Mouse with Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I have a simple script to move and look around when I turn the camera doesn't turn with the character how do I make them turn together.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform PlayerTransform;
    private Vector3 _cameraOffset;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1;
    public Transform Target, Player;
    float mouseX, mouseY;

    [Range(0.01f, 1.0f)]
    public float SmoothFactor = 0.5f;

    public bool LookAtPlayer = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _cameraOffset = transform.position - PlayerTransform.position;
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        CamControl();
        Vector3 newPos = PlayerTransform.position + _cameraOffset;

        transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, newPos, SmoothFactor);

        /*if(LookAtPlayer){
            transform.LookAt(PlayerTransform);
        }*/
    }
    void CamControl()
    {
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed;
        mouseY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeed * -1;
        mouseY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseY, -35, 60);

        transform.LookAt(Target);

        Target.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, 0);
        Player.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, mouseX, 0);
    }
}
```

[Picture Of Workspace]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think You should make the camera child of the player and then attach this code to the player.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController characterController;
    public float speed;
    private Vector3 camRotation;
    private Transform cam;
    private Vector3 moveDirection;

    [Range(-45, -15)]
    public int minAngle = -30;
    [Range(30, 80)]
    public int maxAngle = 45;
    [Range(50, 500)]
    public int sensitivity = 200;

    private void Awake()
    {
        cam = Camera.main.transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        Rotate();
    }

    private void Rotate()
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));

        camRotation.x -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        camRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(camRotation.x, minAngle, maxAngle);

        cam.localEulerAngles = camRotation;
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        float horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontalMove, 0, verticalMove);
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        }

        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Please do not forget to add a Character Controller to the player, and then assign it in the inspector.

Comment: it worked but it's in first person instead of third person is there a way to make it in 3rd person.

Comment: yes, make the camera child of the player and then set camera's Z position to -10 and attach the script to the player.

Comment: yea that's what I did this is what it looks like but its still in first person: https://imgur.com/a/X09elob

Comment: Attach the script to the Capsule and then click on the Main Camera and reset its position. then further decrease the Z position of the main camera. try to play with that until you get the desired results.

Comment: Oh that worked thank you so much I would up rep but I only have 11 rep :(

Comment: Thanks, I am glad I could help.